# Bash `install -d` for existing file with same name

Tags: bash

If a part of my bash script is to copy installation files to a directory:
`install -d DIRECTORY` but already there's a file named `DIRECTORY` , bash reports an error that file already exists. How can I resolve this?

Eg:
`install -d bash_completion.d` . Some software, previously installed, has a *file* name `bash_completion.d` in the exact same location, so `make install` fails.

Is the only option to check using `if-else` or is there some neater way of doing this? Some theory could help.